# jQuery :last selector not working

Tags: jquery, html

```js
$('.data_row:last').after('<tr class="odd"> <td class="first data" style="min-width: 29px;">2</td></tr>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="odd" class="data_row">
    <td class="first data" style="min-width: 29px;">1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Anyone can please tell me why it not working. How can I make it workable? And also please explain Why it not working. so next time I will take care of it.

Comment: tr is not adding. the selector is not working.

Comment: try with :last-child

Comment: Because use have invalid HTML.You have two times the class attribute.

Answer (score 5):

As of now you are using multiple class attribute see  In HTML5 PR, section 8.1.2.3 [Attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0)

> There must never be two or more attributes on the same start tag whose names are an ASCII case-insensitive match for each other.

Second `class` attribute is ignored, thus you need to use single class attribute with `<TR>` element.

```
<tr class="odd data_row">       
</tr>
```

instead of

```
<tr class="odd" class="data_row">
</tr>
```

```js
$('.data_row:last').after('<tr class="odd"> <td class="first data" style="min-width: 29px;">2</td></tr>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="odd data_row">
    <td class="first data" style="min-width: 29px;">1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.data_row').last().css('background', 'red');
```

```css
.data_row {
height:50px;
width:60px;
margin-bottom:10px;
border:1px solid blue;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data_row"></div>
<div class="data_row"></div>
<div class="data_row"></div>
```

Try using `$('.data_row').last()` instead of `$('.data_row:last')` with jQuery.

Comment: The problem is not the selector, they both work. The problem is the double class attributes.

Comment: @ShahRushabh Yes it does work, check my updated answer as proof. You also need to remove your duplicate class

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It definitely works, run the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I feel its better using the following approach.

```
$('table').append('<tr class="odd"> <td class="first data" style="min-width: 29px;"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 258px;" colspan="2"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 79px;"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 39px;"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 59px;"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 79px;"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 39px;"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 39px;"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 79px;"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 79px;"></td></tr>');
```

why? Since you are making Jquery to search the last TD then appending on it after that, but my above code. I feel only table is queried and insertion is always done on the last.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title> </title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
 $('.data').append('<tr class="odd"> <td class="first data" style="min-width: 29px;"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 258px;" colspan="2"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 79px;"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 39px;"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 59px;"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 79px;"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 39px;"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 39px;"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 79px;"></td><td class="first data" style="min-width: 79px;"></td></tr>');
$('.first').last().css( "background-color", "red" );

}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>  
<table class="data">


</table> 

</body>
```

Comment: Please always provide an explanation with your code and try to use the snipper builder (ctrl + m).